# Please share some insights on rehash method in java?

Tags: java, api, hash, hashtable

I am looking for some better insight on hashtable/hash-map data-structure.

By going through the api I could make out that inner Entry class is referrred to as bucket. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Please find the following method:-

```
  public synchronized V put(K key, V value) {
    // Make sure the value is not null
    if (value == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    // Makes sure the key is not already in the hashtable.
    Entry tab[] = table;
    int hash = hash(key);
    int index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;
    for (Entry<K,V> e = tab[index] ; e != null ; e = e.next) {
        if ((e.hash == hash) && e.key.equals(key)) {
            V old = e.value;
            e.value = value;
            return old;
        }
    }

    modCount++;
    if (count >= threshold) {
        // Rehash the table if the threshold is exceeded
        rehash();

        tab = table;
        hash = hash(key);
        index = (hash & 0x7FFFFFFF) % tab.length;
    }

    // Creates the new entry.
    Entry<K,V> e = tab[index];  <-------are we assigining null to this entry?
    tab[index] = new Entry<>(hash, key, value, e);
    count++;
    return null;
}
```

By the following line of code

```
Entry<K,V> e = tab[index];
```

I can assume that we are assigning null to this new entry object; Please correct me here also.

So my another question is :-

why are we not doing this directly

```
Entry<K,V> e = null 
 instead  of 
Entry<K,V> e = tab[index];
```

Please find below is the screen shot for the debug also:-
[image]

Please share your valuable insights on this.

Comment: How did you decide that `tab[index]` is always null? It clearly says that it's assigning `tab[index]`. If they wanted to assign null, they would assign null.

Comment: We are calculating index in this method, and we are also checking if the the key/value pair is present at this index. If nothing is present at the index  in that case i think tab[index] would be null. Please correct me if I am wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Entry<K,V>` is an instance that can represent a link in a linked list. Note that the `next` member refers to the next Entry on the list.

A bucket contains a linked list of entries that were mapped to the same index.

`Entry<K,V> e = tab[index]` will return null only if there's no Entry stored in that index yet. Otherwise it will return the first Entry in the linked list of that bucket.

`tab[index] = new Entry<>(hash, key, value, e);` creates a new Entry and stores it as the first Entry in the bucket. The previous first Entry is passed to the Entry constructor, in order to become the next (second) Entry in the list.

Comment: i have one more question, I may sound novice to you. Can an index in the inner class Entry have multiple different keys.

Comment: @Ankit I'm not sure I follow your question. An Entry instance has one key and one value. What do you mean by "an index in the inner class Entry"?

Comment: I will try to explain my confusion.Please bear with me. I meant to say that we are calculating index, based on which api is traversing the inner Entry object; so I am curious to know that if Entry object for the found index could contain references to other entries that might have different keys.

Comment: @Ankit Yes, of course. Each key appears at most once in the map, so two Entries will have two different keys. Different keys may be mapped to the same bucket of the map, in which case their respective entries will belong to the same linked list.